# background-color issue on table <tr> scale transition

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm having issues while applying scale on a tr hover effect.

When changing the background on hover there are no separation on `<td>` elements, but when applying a scale transformation this appears:

Basic background color change on hover

[image]

**Scale** on hover, some separation appears between `<td>`

[image]

```
table tr:hover {
   background: rgba( 221, 51, 51, .4);
   transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Is there a way to prevent this or solve it ?

```css
table {
  min-width:360px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}


table tr {
  transition: .2s;
}

table tr:hover {
  background: rgba( 221, 51, 51, .4);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>sample</td>
<td>text</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>sample</td>
<td>text</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>sample</td>
<td>text</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>sample</td>
<td>text</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Adding border-collapse: collapse on the table seems to improve the thing on chrome but there's still a tiny line

Comment: Just edited my snippet adding Bootstrap's styles for new users to be in better position to found a solution

Comment: I don't see the line at all in the snippet, nor in this fiddle that includes your code and bootstrap styles: https://jsfiddle.net/hkwzv62c/.  This tells me you must have some other styles in your application causing this.  Can you include all the styles that apply to the table, it's children and the text inside the cells?

Comment: @RobertWade here is a live version of what I am trying https://test.cemk.es, after testing up a bit, in Chrome and Opera a tiny separator space appears, in Firefox the problem is not visible, and Explorer and Edge doesn't run the transformation.

Comment: @RobertWade just got it, changing border-collapse: collapse; to border-collapse: 0; by default it's value is 0 but on hovering it becomes "collapse"

Comment: Yes, i just discovered the same and provided a similar answer.  For some reason `collapse` is causing it.  Letting it default to `separate` seems to do the trick.  Fair warning, `0` is not a proper value for border collapse, so by you putting that in there, it's just defaulting to `separate`. Possible values for border-collapse are `separate|collapse|initial|inherit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I toyed around with your live example and noticed that it only seems to show that line when the table is fairly wide.  Toggling a few of the styles in the inspector also showed that when you turn off:

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

And it defaults back to:

```
border-collapse: separate;
```

The line goes away. `separate` is the default value for this, so simply overriding the `collapse` value or removing it entirely should do the trick.